# Which one is correct "at an" or "in an"?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

• I am an engineer, and I work "at an" office.

OR

• I am an engineer, and I work "in an" office.

If both are correct, what is the difference between them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your research suggest? This is a very, very basic question. You might feel more comfortable at [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), but they would also ask for some kind of research.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine and mean the same thing. The second is more common.

Don't use in advance. Since we couldn't possibly see the question until it was written and posted, it was obviously in advance.

Just say "Thank you" or Thanks."

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment at the very most.